# Strange white space between html tag and body

Tags: javascript, html, css, document-body

I'm trying to get a full-screen image background with a scrollable div on its center, so I wrote this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bio</title>
<link href="../css/layout-base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready(function(){
        var background = $('#background');
        var scrollable = $('#scrollable-container');
        var halfWhite = $('#halfWhite');
        var halfBlack = $('#halfBlack');
        /* calcolo dimensione finestra */
        var maxWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxHeight = $(window).height();

        /* settaggio dimensioni immagine sfondo */
        background.css("height",maxHeight);
        background.css("width",maxWidth);

        scrollable.css("height",maxHeight);

        /* settaggio dimensioni riempimento sfondo */
        halfWhite.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfWhite.css("width",maxWidth/2);
        halfBlack.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfBlack.css("width",maxWidth/2);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="halfWhite"></div>
    <div id="halfBlack"></div>
    <div id="scrollable-container">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="home" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/bio1.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="events" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/events2.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="gallery" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/gallery3.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="disco" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/disco4.png"/></a>
        </div><!--div content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- div background -->
</body>
</html>
```

With the relative css:

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
margin:0!important;
}
#background{
background-image:url(../media/index/back.png);
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#halfWhite{
position:relative;
background-color: white;
z-index: -10;
float: left;
}
#halfBlack{
position:relative;
background-color: black;
z-index: -10;
float: right;
}
#scrollable-container{margin-left: 15%;margin-right: 15%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.00)}
.content{
margin-top:1%;
height:100%;
position: relative;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-right: 5%;
box-shadow: -10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
-moz-box-shadow:-10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
-webkit-box-shadow:-10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.menu{width:15%}
.menu img{width:100%}
#home{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
#events{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;}
#gallery{position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;}
#disco{position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;}
```

The result seems good, but I noticed that there's a strange white space between the html tag and the body...how can I avoid this behaviour? What could be its cause?
Unfortunately I'm pretty new on web development, so I don't even know if this is a proper way to get this layout. 
Does anyone has some tips?

Comment: Have you tried setting the padding and margin to 0 for body?

Comment: yes, but it seems on the ispector that the body has no padding, while the html tag is greater than the body size

Comment: The content class inside of scrollable-container has a margin top of 1%, sorry did not notice the link before

Comment: yes, but why this does affect the parent position as well?
I want the content class element to have a margin top, but the background to stay on top of the page...should i set the position instead of setting a margin?

Comment: I am sure there is a good explanation of why this happens and I am sure I read it before but I forgot. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can try removing the margin top and add padding top to #scrollable-container. This is what I think you are trying to do

Comment: I think this is it http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin issue as mentioned in my comments collapsing margins

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

You can remove the margin top from .content and add padding-top to the container `#scrollable-container`

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do but I think it is

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do, but now how can I make the .content class scroll and the rest of the page to stay fixed?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but you should ask that in another question when you run into this issue after trying something

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the 1% `margin-top` on `.content` (Line 26 of layout-base.css)

Margins can sort of push out of their parents sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#background{
margin:0;
background-image:url(../media/index/back.png);
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

if that doesn't work try getting rid of `margin-top:1%;` and zeroing it out in `.content`